# Link a binary framework to both Pod Target and main app project

Tags: swift, frameworks, cocoapods

I have a library project which was installed via Pod into my main project. That library project use a framework. I didn't or actually couldn't embed that framework in the library project cause of making Umbrella Project and this is not recommended by Apple.

So I tried to embed it in my main project but the library project in Pod couldn't see it so that lead to error "No such module"

So how I can link the framework which embedded in the main project to that library pod target.

Answer (score 0):

Ok. I'm able to make it work. Just drag the folder on main project which contain the framework in your pod target project framework search path. It will automatically transform a path like this

"$(SRCROOT)/../"